# Why does CSS :root head show throughout all HTML files in Heroku?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, heroku

I am making a website using PHP to open a static website on Heroku.

I have a problem where everything is fine before deploying on Heroku. Once it is deployed suddenly there are CSS :root head code showing as plain text on all the html files. Here is a picture.

[image]

When I do inspect it shows that the plain text is part of the head element. I don't get why it is showing, I don't know if it's because of something to do with PHP or just Heroku. Please help.

Here is some CSS code I have for the file and html stuff too. (This is in the file base.css)

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Kumbh Sans", sans-serif;
  display: block;
}

head {
  display: none;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #b6bcc2;
  /*border-bottom: 5px solid white;*/
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

(This is in the file home.html) There are no  tags and I have only used  tags.

```
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Project H.E.L.L.O.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/base.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/home.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
```

Here is also the only PHP I used :

```
<?php include_once("html/home.html") ;
```

I also have a composer.json file with {} and nothing else.

Comment: Are you adding the CSS directly in the html before the head as in the snippet you attached? If so, please move it inside your other .css files or include it in a <style> tag inside the head.
Also may I ask what is the use of the `type="text/css"` on the link tag? As per this source https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_type.asp it should not be used on the link tag but on the style tag.

Comment: @WeamAdel https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_type.asp

Comment: I am not adding css directly into html, I am using the <link> tags and I have no <style> tags. It still doesn't work even when I put the type="text/css" inside the style tag.@WeamAdel